# Firebase Authentication credential.js CertCredential.prototype.getAccessToken is erratically working

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

We develop in the context of the SMARNET01 Firebase Project, an app which uses Firebase Database and Authentication. We use it for developing a Windows 7 with NodeJS 4.5 machine. All is working normally using both API key and later, `serviceAccountCredentials` because we have to call `verifyIdToken`.

So when we deploy this in a Docker(*which got from DockerHub official NodeJS site*) the API key is working, but the `serviceAccountCredentials` doesn´t. The curious thing is that it is working in the Ubuntu 14.04 VM which contains the docker.

At a different Ubuntu 14.04 VM we raised for this purpose, wasn't able to make it work, neither in the VM nor in the Docker. We tried using different versions of NodeJS(*v0.10.25, v0.10.46 & v4.5*).

After some digging in the SDK code, we discovered a promise which is not resolved due to a REST call to Google which is never answered (*it dies for time out long time after*). The call is located in the method `CertCredential.prototype.getAccessToken` in the `credentials.js` of the `auth-node` folder of the SDK.

I tried this call with the Insomnia REST client and it works. We tried different ways to fix that, for instance, check that NTP is synchronized, and checked different suggestions in the internet.

When it stops, the Firebase log stops in:

```
p:0: Browser went online.
p:0: Making a connection attempt
```

When it works the logging continuos in this way:

```
p:0: Browser went online.
p:0: Making a connection attempt
p:0: Auth token refreshed
getToken() completed. Creating connection.
c:0:0: Connection created
c:0:0:0 Websocket connecting to wss://smarnet01.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5
c:0:0:0 Websocket connected.
c:0:0: Reset packet received.  New host: s-usc1c-nss-135.firebaseio.com
...............
```

Does anyone have any idea what is happening? Thanks in advance.